# Imprimir un pdf después de cada Informe

Tags: vba, ms-access

```html
        Try
            Using p As New Process
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "archivo.pdf"
                p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
                p.Start()

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) ' tiempo X para que el programa cliente se active he imprima

                p.CloseMainWindow() ' Cierre ventana cliente
                ' si la ventana sigue abierta, se encicla hasta cerrarla.
                While Not p.HasExited
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                    p.CloseMainWindow()
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Cual es el evento que hace después de imprimir cada registro? 
Os cuento el reto porque necesito ayuda.
Tengo un informe con varios registros. En estos algunos tienen un campo con un enlace a un plano. Quiero que al imprimir el informe, si el campo plano tienen plano me lo imprima después del informe.

Gracias.

Estoy probando con este código que funciona pero cuando lo llevo a Access97 no lo entiende. Alguien lo puede traducir a vba de Access97????
Llevo días con esto...

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en Español. Has etiquetado la pregunta con VBA, así que podrías programarte un código que hiciese una consulta, basada en los registros de tu informe, pero filtrando solo por los que tienen el enlace al plano. Lleva los enlaces a una matriz, y hazte un bucle para que te vaya imprimiendo cada plano.

Comment: El access es el 97 y no se como hacerlo. Cual es el evento de imprimir porque para el access es lo mismo que ver en pantalla.

Comment: En Access 97 no sé, pero en 2007 es `Private Sub Report_Page()` el evento. Tienes más info en https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.report.page(even)